# How can I force a dictionary in python to reject updates of existing keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it possible to design a dictionary in Python in a way that if by mistake a key which is already in the dictionary is added, it gets rejected?
thanks

Comment: I would like to point out that "unique keys" are inherent property of a dictionary.  When you insert a key / value pair, it updates any prior entries that would lead to duplicate keys.  Your question, therefore threw my for a loop. Now, as I read this more closely I understand that what you are asking for is to prevent such updates - which is a valid and understandable extension.  I just wanted clarify this for other readers, so they aren't confused into thinking they need to prevent duplicate keys in a more generalized sense.

Comment: ^ Yes and as we see in user2197172's answer below, using 'setdefault' is the complement: it quietly swallows attempts to add duplicate keys.

Comment: I submitted an edit of the question to accurately reflect what the user was really asking. Now it sounds like a useful question (how do you change Python's default behaviour?), rather than a completely redundant one (how do you make Python do what it already enforces?).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can always create your own dictionary

```
class UniqueDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self:
            dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
        else:
            raise KeyError("Key already exists")
```

Comment: Note that the `__init__` method is not actually needed when it does nothing but call the parent `__init__` with the same arguments.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, but I'm not in love with the name of this class.  See my comment on the initial question.  Maybe something like "InsertOnlyDict" or "NoUpdateDict" etc. would be more clear?

Comment: Call it whatever you want. It really doesn't matter. No I am not editing this answer.

Comment: Is it possible to add value if key is already present. Like else:
            dict.__setitem__(self, key, self.value + value). I tried doing this but its just updating value.

Comment: This will still swallow duplicate keys when they are passed to the constructor, e.g., UniqueDict([('a',1),('a',1)]) returns {'a': 1}

Answer (score 5):

Just check your dict before you add the item

```
if 'k' not in mydict:
    mydict.update(myitem)
```

Comment: you can just do : `if 'k' not in mydict` without the `.keys()` :)

Comment: @singularity: You SHOULD (not can) avoid the `.keys()` ... it's a gross waste of resources.

Comment: Sorry, that was an oversight. Fixed it in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is the purpose of setdefault:

```
>>> x = {}
>>> print x.setdefault.__doc__
D.setdefault(k[,d]) -> D.get(k,d), also set D[k]=d if k not in D
>>> x.setdefault('a', 5)
5
>>> x
{'a': 5}
>>> x.setdefault('a', 10)
5
>>> x
{'a': 5}
```

This also means you can skip "if 'key' in dict: ... else: ..."

```
>>> for val in range(10):
...     x.setdefault('total', 0)
...     x['total']+=val
...
0
0
1
3
6
10
15
21
28
36
>>> x
{'a': 5, 'total': 45}
```

Comment: This is a cute answer, and in fact duplicate keys are quietly swallowed -- is that the same as "rejected", though?  No exception is raised.

Comment: You're right to point out the 'rejected' requirement and if that means throwing an exception then this does fail. My assumption was that "rejected" was relative to the update of the value in the dict and not indicative of error handling.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom dictionary by deriving from `dict` and overriding [`__setitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) to reject items already in the dictionary.

Comment: @Hossein: @Jakobs answer provides an example.